# Prompt user for info on Send then add that info to the mail being sent

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to prompt the user to enter their name in an input box, when they hit Send.

Once they input the info and click Ok, I want to append the name to the end of the message and then let the message go.

Comment: Why not just use Signatures? :-) Any other reason?

Comment: Well.. the Outlook account is in a multi-user environment, and users always forget to put their name before sending the reply. There is no way to tell which user sent that email from that one account.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
SenderName = InputBox("Please enter your name")
Item.Body = Item.Body + SenderName
End Sub
```

This is a simple script to do the job.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also tell how to deploy this in Outlook?

Comment: VBA uses "&" to concatenate strings, not "+".

Comment: You have to paste Shoban's code into Outlook's ThisOutlookSession module in the VBA editor. Restart Outlook and test it by sending an email.